# How would I graph the top half of a circle with only a y=... equation? Is it possible?

Tags: trigonometry

I've been playing around with normal trigonometry making circles and waves. I make circles like this:

> $y = \cos(t)$
>
> $t \in [0,2\pi)$
>
> $x = \sin(t)$

Simple. I was wondering, could I graph the **top half** of a circle ONLY using $x$, and graphing by $y$? As in something like

> $y=\cos(x+\sin(x))$

Which I understand doesn't work. Something that would make a wave, but have it warped like the top/bottom half of a circle If you could give me an equation with reasoning, or a answer of why it wouldn't work, that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: $y=\sqrt {1-x^2}$ for $x\in [-1,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! And cool, it does work. Any reasoning why?

Comment: A circle is the locus of points equidistant from a given point.  If the given point is $(0,0)$ and the radius is $1$ we get $x^2+y^2=1$ or $y^2=1-x^2$.  As you want $y≥0$ just take the positive square root.

Comment: @Blake Define distance in the $x,y$ plane.  A circle is just the special case of when the distance from $(0,0)$ is fixed.

Comment: Awesome. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Asin}{Arcsin}$You've got a good answer in the comments, but in the spirit of your question: The equation
$$
x = \sin t,\quad -1 \leq x \leq 1,
$$
can be written
$$
t = \Asin x,\quad -\pi/2 \leq t \leq \pi/2.
$$
This *principal branch* of arcsine satisfies $\sin(\Asin x) = x$ for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.

Substituting into $y = \cos t$ and using
$$
\cos t = \sqrt{1 - \sin^{2}t},\quad -\pi/2 \leq t \leq \pi/2,
$$
gives
$$
y = \cos(\Asin x) = \sqrt{1 - x^{2}},\quad -1 \leq x \leq 1.
$$

Comment: That really helps. Thanks for explaining in detail :)